# Blender 2.79 undo "partially" applies

Tags: system

I hit a ctrl-Z problem : the undo **works** in edit mode but **won't apply** in object mode.
Undo history (ctrl-Alt-Z) won't show neither.
I get the same behaviour in the History buttons of the Tools panel...
Any clue on this ?
Thanks,
Fred

Comment: I was in the same state.
Please check User Preferences < Editing < Undo < Global Undo

Comment: Ohhh, great ! Thanks a lot !This option must be unchecked by default since 2.79, Never had this problem before